# sed N and P multiline command option doesn't work as is expected

Tags: sed

Data sample:

```
output=$(cat <<EOF
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
This is line 6.
EOF
)
echo "${output}" > ~/data8.txt
```

why two below lines return the same?

```
sed '{
N
3,$P
}' ~/data8.txt

This is line 1. 
This is line 2. 
This is line 3. 
This is line 3. 
This is line 4. 
This is line 5. 
This is line 5. 
This is line 6.


sed '{
N
4,$P
}' ~/data8.txt
```

I'll expect above line return:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
This is line 4.
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
This is line 5.
This is line 6.
```

But it returns:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
This is line 3.
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
This is line 5.
This is line 6.
```

Please your help in the weird behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When line 3 is read, line 4 is added by the `N` command, so the address `4,$` matches and the `P` command is executed, printing the first line in the buffer, which is line 3.

The result is the same because line 3 and 4 are read together, so it doesn't matter whether the address says `3,$` or `4,$`.

Comment: In that scenario when `N ; 3,$` is executed: shouldn't line `This is line 2.` shouldn't it be duplicate?.

Comment: You start with line 1. `N` appends line 2 to the buffer. The address doesn't match, so the buffer with both lines is printed. Next cycle starts with line 3; `N` appends line 4. Address matches, so the buffer uptp the first newline (= line 3) is printed. Afterwards the whole buffer (lines 3 and 4). Add command `l` after the `N` is you still can't follow.